# string function not returning string? c++

Tags: c++, string, function, parsing

I'm sorry. I'm a bit new here and I'm not really sure where to post it. But I'm making a packet parser.

The program is suppose to open a file(that is in binary string) and then convert it into numbers(for the IP) and letters( the poem lines itself)

I'm stuck at my string function which takes a string from the file and then converts it into a sentence. I tested my binary to ascii converter and it works fine. I also tested returning a set string("string line=" banana") in my string poem_line function and it returns it just fine too.

I also tested the loop and it prints the binary string of the line needed to be changed just right.

I don't know what else is wrong.

```
string poem_Line(int packe,int datal, char p){
    int m=0;
    int start_where=0;

    string line;
    string transformed;

    start_where=packe-datal; //this is the 32+32+16+16+16

    ifstream inFile_data("cases_random.in");

    if(inFile_data.is_open()){

        for(m=0; m<packe; m++){

            inFile_data>>p;

            if(m>=start_where){
                int q=0;
                line[q]=p;
                q++;
            }
        }

        inFile_data.close();
        transformed=binaryAscii(line);
     }
     else
        cout<<"is not open"<<endl;


     return transformed;

}
```

[full code](http://dpaste.com/01HYA72)!

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: The string function doesn't return anything, or doesn't appear to return anything when I try to print it in main

Comment: Please pose a [mcve].

Comment: I believe that you're having trouble, but [Stack Overflow is a question and answer site](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).  "I'm stuck" isn't a question.

Comment: that's the thing. It works in every way except  in this form.

Comment: You're only writing to `line[0]`. (Which is undefined at the moment, but you probably want to fix that too.)

Answer (score 1):

This line:

```
string line;
```

Creates an empty string.

This line:

```
line[q]=p;
```

Tries to write to string at position that is not allocated (memory you don't own, and your string object would not know about because its managed string size is 0. This is undefined behaviour)

I suggest you `.resize()` your string after creation, if you know target size, or simply use `+=` p to add chars to it:

```
line += p;
```

Comment: "not sure why it doesn't crash for you" - Undefined Behaviour is not guaranteed to cause a crash. It can result in whatever behaviour.

Comment: @JesperJuhl Right, triggers debug assert in debug though

Answer (score 0):

Your `line` length equals to zero. Do `line.push_back(p);` instead of `line[q]=p;`. push_back resizes string and increase its length. `line[q]=p;` - in this case you are writing to another memory which doesn't belong to `line`, you can rewrite something important data by your overwriting.